# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::OR()

Tags: codeigniter

I am making a simple contact form and got this error.

> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::OR()

here is my code
`$this->db->OR(like('p.post_title', $search), like('p.post_body', $search));`